# MySQL query copying data from one table to another randomly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this existing sql query that is working quite fine.  It searches in a table called qu_pap_users under a particular field (userid) and then randomly grabs a userid to copy into a different table called settings...

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO qu_g_settings (settingid, name, value) 
        SELECT '9038fa14', 'assignNonReferredAffiliateTo', qu_pap_users.userid 
        FROM qu_pap_users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

I would like to change the last part of the query so that it does the following:

1. Locate the userid field as above, but now it needs to look into an additional field called data12.
2. I want it to only copy userids where the data12 field = Affiliate Distributor Licensed
3. After it has found all userids with a data12 field that = Affiliate Distributor Licensed, I would like it to then randomly select from those userids only.

I hope this is clear enough.  Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You have to just add where clause to filter data12 field = Affiliate Distributor Licensed

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO qu_g_settings (settingid, name, value) 
        SELECT '9038fa14', 'assignNonReferredAffiliateTo', 
                qu_pap_users.userid
        FROM qu_pap_users
        WHERE qu_pap_users.data12 = 'Affiliate Distributor Licensed'
        ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for such a fast response.  Works great!!